# Setting a non-image as MediaWiki wiki logo

Tags: mediawiki

How can I use .swf file as my logo ? I found out that in LocalSettings.php

```
$wgLogo= "$wgStylePath/common/images/wiki.png";
```

I can change my logo through this line , but it only supports images , how can I use .swf or .fla file instead of an image ?

Comment: Why flash? What does your logo contain? Does not sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logo should always be an image, it might be shown in various locations. Create a png version of your `swf` file if possible.

The logo shown in the top left (at least in Monobook and Vector skin) is by default an anchor element (with a link towards the main page), with the logo file set as a background image. If you want to replace it with something different, you will need to edit the skin template(s). In monobook, for example, it would be the [code around line 125](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=skins/MonoBook.php;h=955f05bedaee1a3756c5b4ed74db353b2e223460;hb=HEAD#l122).